# Convert two list in one list from R

Tags: r, list, tags

I got two list

```
var1=c("fe1","fe2")
var2=c("A1","A2")
```

I try to do that with a loop for

```
list_final  <- list("fe1" = "A1", "fe2" = "A2")
```

My code is there

```
library("rlist")

list_final <-list()
for(i in var1) {
  for(d in var2) {
    x = setNames(i, paste0(d))
    list.append(list_final,x)
}
}
```

But the list is always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also a loop approach can be useful:

```
#Data
var1=c("fe1","fe2")
var2=c("A1","A2")
#List
List <- list()
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(var1))
{
  List[[var1[i]]]<-var2[i]
}
List
```

Output:

```
List
$fe1
[1] "A1"

$fe2
[1] "A2"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `setNames` to create a named `vector` and convert to a `list` with `as.list` in `base R` (without using a `for` loop)

```
list_final2 <- as.list(setNames(var2, var1))
```

-checking with OP's expected

```
identical(list_final, list_final2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have *unique*  values in `var1`, you can try the code below with `split`

```
> split(var2,var1)
$fe1
[1] "A1"

$fe2
[1] "A2"
```

Otherwise, the method by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64178930/12158757) should be applied

Answer (score 0):

just like this:
`as.list(names(var2)<-var1)`

Comment: @Summers Please add some explanation by editing the answer.